# How does one retrieve and manipulate ndb StructuredProperty objects?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Here is an example of [StructuredProperty from the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured):

```
class Address(ndb.Model):
    type = ndb.StringProperty() # E.g., 'home', 'work'
    street = ndb.StringProperty()
    city = ndb.StringProperty()

class Contact(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    addresses = ndb.StructuredProperty(Address, repeated=True)

guido = Contact(name='Guido',
                addresses=[Address(type='home',
                                   city='Amsterdam'),
                           Address(type='work',
                                   street='Spear St',
                                   city='SF')])

guido.put()
```

Imagine that Guido is temporarily in the city of Timbuktu, Mali for work. How would I go about retrieving and updating just his work address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try something like this.

```
for address in guido.addresses:
    if address.type == 'work':
        address.street = "Main Street"
        address.city = "Timbuktu"

guido.put()
```

**EDIT**
added a colon

Comment: Thanks, @Hans Then. You missed a colon, but otherwise the code works :)